# Why `boost::bind()` can't be replaced with `std::bind()` here?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, bind, boost-asio

In this part of code from the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5/src.html):

```
int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  printer p(io);
  boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
  io.run();
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

If I replace the `boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io)` to `std::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io)` I get the compilation error:

```
.../usr/lib/c++/v1/functional:1843:1: note: candidate template
  ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Fp'
bind(_Fp&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __bound_args)
^
/usr/lib/c++/v1/functional:1852:1: note: candidate template
  ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Rp'
bind(_Fp&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __bound_args)
^
1 error generated.
```

Why this error happen?

Why `std::bind(&printer::print1, &p)` works, but `std::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io)` doesn't work?

Comment: Add all lines of your error message.

Comment: `boost::thread` has a forwarding constructor, so you don't need bind at all: `boost::thread t(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io);`

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is telling you that it could not figure out the type of the first argument to `std::bind`.

If you look at `io_service::run`, you will see that it is overloaded. The compiler had a choice, and this is a possible reason for the compiler not figuring out the type. To test this, you can use a cast:

```
std::bind(static_cast<size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()>(&boost::asio::io_service::run), &io)
```

This way makes the choice explicit in the code.

With a modern compiler, you don't need to use bind at all. You can do something like this:

```
[&]() { io.run(); }
```

That avoids all the problems with the `std::bind` template. You need to consider variable lifetime and copies vs. references.

Comment: thank you, but it also can not cast to `std::function<size_t ()>`, but it can work when I case it to `std::size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()`, boost::bind can deal with the overload function, maybe lambda function is more help!

Comment: `std::function<size_t ()>` doesn't have a constructor accepting a pointer to member function (not to mention that creating `std::function` here is absolutely unnecessary overhead).

Comment: @IgorR. Yes, you are right. I wrote "cast" in the text, but then typed something else entirely! Will fix the code.

Comment: @user2763477 As IgorR pointed out, my code doesn't match my text. Updated; was typing too quickly!